# How do I decode url data and access in array and decode % value from urls

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying this code to get info from json and array but I can't decode %values from the data and can't access the array any one can help me?

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/video?&video_id=MvK7ibgRREw&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $data;
```

Comment: i want to access like this {"22":{
"url":"example url","type":"video\/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2\"","quality":"hd720"}

Comment: Why are you using headers?

Comment: @AndreFerraz dear sir i'm using header for json response but i can't i don't know more about php or json etc i'm student

Comment: You should parse the result. First url decode (i guess), then a http query split and then a json_encode. And students should read, try a lot and then ask on 'how to solve it' ;-)

Comment: @Marien dear i start some time ago i don't know about this can you write this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work...

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=MvK7ibgRREw&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US';
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$array = explode('&', $data);

for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
    $array[$i] = urldecode($array[$i]);
}

$json = json_encode($array);

echo $json;
```

Comment: but after json arry encode url still have % data are not decode

Comment: how to i replace percent %26 and other %value in this data